# Flutter How to add Watermark on image when image share

Tags: flutter, watermark

here is my code for image share now i want Share image with some texting watermark on it...! i seen
such articles they are showing drwaString but could not get it...plz can u help me ?? to water mark on
Share button..

```
  void _onShare() async {
  var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(imagepath));
  var response = await request.close();
  Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
  await Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', '.jpg', bytes, 'image/jpg',text: "Hello");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do so by using the [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image)

The full tutorial can be found [in this medium article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-watermark-over-image-in-flutter-e7353e3cf603) but you can have a look at this snippet

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ui;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  

  File _originalImage;
  File _watermarkImage;
  File _watermarkedImage;
  
  applyWaterMark() async {
    ui.Image originalImage = ui.decodeImage(_originalImage.readAsBytesSync());
    ui.Image watermarkImage = ui.decodeImage(_watermarkImage.readAsBytesSync());

    // add watermark over originalImage
    // initialize width and height of watermark image
    ui.Image image = ui.Image(160, 50);
    ui.drawImage(image, watermarkImage);

    // give position to watermark over image
    // originalImage.width - 160 - 25 (width of originalImage - width of watermarkImage - extra margin you want to give)
    // originalImage.height - 50 - 25 (height of originalImage - height of watermarkImage - extra margin you want to give)
    ui.copyInto(originalImage,image, dstX: originalImage.width - 160 - 25, dstY: originalImage.height - 50 - 25);


    // for adding text over image
    // Draw some text using 24pt arial font
    // 100 is position from x-axis, 120 is position from y-axis
    ui.drawString(originalImage, ui.arial_24, 100, 120, 'Think Different');

    // Store the watermarked image to a File
    List<int> wmImage = ui.encodePng(originalImage);
    setState(() {
      _watermarkedImage = File.fromRawPath(Uint8List.fromList(wmImage));
    });

  }
}
```